# stop listening to context React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The component listens to the context. Each context update triggers a rerender. Can I stop listening to the context if I already got the right value?
I want to stop further component update when this context changes

For example

```
const {contextValue, setContextValue}= useContext(MyContext)
if (contextValue == 'stop listen') {stop listening}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to wrangle a `useContext` invocation into a custom hook that wouldn't cause a rerender when the context value changes. However we can achieve similar functionality in a higher order component.

```js
const withContextValue = Component => (props) => {
  const context = useContext(MyContext);
  const contextRef = useRef(context);
  if (contextRef.current.contextValue !== 'stop listen')
    contextRef.current = context;
  return <Component {...props} context={contextRef.current} />;  
};
```

Provided you pass a memoized component to `withContextValue` you'll receive a component that will rerender on every context value change but the memoized component will not rerender unlike in the case where `useContext` was invoked inside the memoized component.

---

The above pattern can be unwieldy to work with and doesn't eliminate rerenders completely. For a better developer experience you may want to try a subscription pattern where each consumer of a context gets to define what changes cause a rerender. Famously `react-redux` uses this pattern.

Define your context value as a mutable object.

```js
class ContextValue {
  constructor() {
    this.subscribers = [];
    this.contextValue = '';
  }

  setContextValue(action) {
    const prevValue = this.contextValue;
    this.contextValue =
      typeof action === 'function'
        ? action(this.contextValue)
        : action;
    if (prevValue !== this.contextValue)
      this.subscribers.forEach(subscriber => subscriber(this.contextValue));
  }
  
  subscribe(subscriber) {
    this.subscribers.push(subscriber);
    return () => void (this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(sub => sub !== subscriber));
  }
}

export const Provider = () => {
  const context = useRef(new ContextValue()).current;
  return <MyContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
};

export const useMyContext = (equalityFn = () => false) => {
  const [, rerender] = useReducer(() => ({}), {});
  const context = useContext(MyContext);
  const equalityFnRef = useRef(equalityFn);
  equalityFn.current = equalityFn;
  useEffect(
    () => context.subscribe(newValue => {
      if (!equalityFnRef.current(context.contextValue, newValue)) rerender();
    }),
    [context.subscriber, context.contextValue]
  );
  return context;
};
```

You can then define any equality function to limit rerenders on a consumer-by-consumer basis just like with Redux's `useSelector`.

```js
const {contextValue, setContextValue}= useMyContext(prevValue => prevValue === 'stop listen');
```

Mind you this pattern will stop unnecessary rerenders but will not stop the component from reading an up-to-date context value if something else causes a rerender. If you need to stop receiving new values you'll want to wrap the hook in an extra layer of memoization.

Answer (score 0):

Consumers of `useContext()` will always re-render whenever the context value changes.

"Even if an ancestor uses React.memo or shouldComponentUpdate, a rerender will still happen starting at the component itself using useContext."

There's a good chance that if you don't always want context changes to trigger a component re-render, then some other means of maintaining that state is better for your use case.

See the [useContext React docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) for more information.